# diagrammeR - adaptation from "how can I add arms to my flowchart?"

Tags: r, graph, flowchart, diagrammer

I found the following example of diagrammeR here ([diagrammer - how can I add arms to my flowchart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014409/diagrammer-how-can-i-add-arms-to-my-flowchart)):

```
library(DiagrammeR)

grViz("digraph flowchart {
  # node definitions with substituted label text
  node [fontname = Helvetica, shape = rectangle, fixedsize = false, width = 1] 
  1 [label = 'data (100%)']
  2 [label = 'data  (74.4%)']
  3 [label = 'data  (69.6%)']
  4 [label = 'data  (55.4%)']
  m1 [label = 'missing (25.6%)']
  m2 [label = 'missing (4.8%)']

  node [shape=none, width=0, height=0, label='']
  p1 -> 2; p2 -> 3 -> 4;
  {rank=same; p1 -> m1}
  {rank=same; p2 -> m2}

  edge [dir=none]
  1 -> p1; 2 -> p2;
}")
```

Output is:

[image]

In my case I have multiple exclusions (m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8) between box 2 and 3:

```
grViz("digraph flowchart {
  # node definitions with substituted label text
  node [fontname = Helvetica, shape = rectangle, fixedsize = false, width = 1] 
  1 [label = 'Box 1']
  2 [label = 'Box 2']
  3 [label = 'Box 3']
  m1 [label = 'm1']
  m2 [label = 'm2']
  m3 [label = 'm3']
  m4 [label = 'm4']
  m5 [label = 'm5']
  m6 [label = 'm6']
  m7 [label = 'm7']
  m8 [label = 'm8']
  
  node [shape=none, width=0, height=0, label='']
  p1 -> 2; p2 -> 3;
  {rank=same; p1 -> m1}
  {rank=same; p2 -> m2}
  {rank=same; p2 -> m3}
  {rank=same; p2 -> m4}
  {rank=same; p2 -> m5}
  {rank=same; p2 -> m6}
  {rank=same; p2 -> m7}
  {rank=same; p2 -> m8}      
  
  edge [dir=none]
  1 -> p1; 2 -> p2;
}")
```

Currently this gives me:
[image]

But I would like to have a longer arrow between box 2 and 3 so that all *m* boxes are one below the other, and not to the right, is this possible? Like:

```
Box 2
  |--- m2
  |--- m3
  |--- m4
  |--- m5
  |--- m6
  |--- m7
  |--- m8
Box 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you up and running. Just add more (`p3 -> p4`... in edge section etc.).

```
library(DiagrammeR)
grViz("digraph flowchart {
  # node definitions with substituted label text
  node [fontname = Helvetica, shape = rectangle, fixedsize = false, width = 1] 
  1 [label = 'Box 1']
  2 [label = 'Box 2']
  3 [label = 'Box 3']

  m1 [label = 'm1']
  m2 [label = 'm2']
  m3 [label = 'm3']
  
  node [shape=none, width=0, height=0, label='']
  p1 -> 2; p3 -> 3
  {rank=same; p1 -> m1}
  {rank=same; p2 -> m2}
  {rank=same; p3 -> m3}
  
  edge [dir=none, arrowhead=none]
  1 -> p1; 2 -> p2; p2 -> p3
}")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Brian, works perfectly! Do you know if there is a way to increase the length of the arrows going to the right?

Comment: Don't have time to test today, but lookls like there is a `minlen` argument that might be helpful. https://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/graphviz_and_mermaid.html